# Find all maximum entries from map in kotlin?

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, max

I would like to find all entries with maximum value.

I've come to:

```
val myMap = mapOf<Int, Int>(...)
val maxEntries = myMap.maxBy { it.value }
        ?.let { max -> myMap.filter { it.value == max.value } }
        ?.entries
        ?: emptySet()
```

but I wonder if there is more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify what you have to something as follows:

```
val maxValue = myMap.values.maxOrNull() // or max() depending on Kotlin version
val maxEntries = myMap.filterValues { it == maxValue }
```

This way you keep the `Map<Int, Int>`-type and I think it's more readable that way. Note that `maxValue` being `null` doesn't really hurt, as you will only get `null` if the map is empty... filtering then on an empty map still returns an empty map. That's probably also the only* bad part of this solution. If you have an empty map, this variant constructs a new empty map when `filterValues` is called.

If you mind that, then the following is more appropriate:

```
val maxEntries = myMap.values.maxOrNull()?.let { maxValue -> 
    myMap.filterValues { it == maxValue }
} ?: emptyMap()
```

* the only bad part besides iterating over the map twice. If you want to overcome that, then I think you have to implement your own specific function dealing with both, checking max value and collecting, at the same time.